# Database Table column data not showing into gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridviewcolumn

I have created a function `loaddata()` to get the records from my database and to display it in my gridview. When I execute it, the `id` column value is not getting displayed.

```
private void loadData()
{
        var userdata = db.getUsers();
        userIDGV.DataPropertyName = "ID";
        userGV.DataPropertyName = "User";
        usernameGV.DataPropertyName = "Username";
        passwordGV.DataPropertyName = "Password";
        phoneGV.DataPropertyName = "Phone";
        addressGV.DataPropertyName = "Address";
        roleNameGV.DataPropertyName = "Role";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = userdata;
        MainClass.sno(dataGridView1, "snoGV");
}
```

This is the query of my stored procedure `getusers()`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getUsers] 
AS
    SELECT 
        u.u_id AS 'ID', 
        u.u_name AS 'User', 
        u.u_uname AS 'Username', 
        u.u_password AS 'Password', 
        u.u_phone AS 'Phone', 
        u.u_address AS 'Address', 
        u.u_rollID AS 'RoleID', 
        r.r_name AS 'Role' 
    FROM
        users u 
    INNER JOIN
        roles r on r.r_id = u.u_rollID 
    ORDER BY 
        u.u_id ASC
```

The value is getting stored in database but it is not getting displayed in the datagridview when I run the `loadData()`. What is the issue? Please help me out.

Comment: Can you confirm when you debug that `userdata` has everything you expect?

Comment: You should *really* use whitespace and line breaks when writing any code. That SP is impossible to read when it's all on a single line.

Comment: What is the structure of the `userdata` variable??

Comment: you are getting id field value in userdata variable ?

Comment: This question is **on topic**.  The `sql-server` suite cannot be off-topic.

Comment: I am getting all the data stored into the database, but when i load that data from database to gridview, all the data are displayed except userIDGV. it shows me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Crowcoder all the details are present except userID.

Comment: What do you mean by "userID".  You have shown no identifier by that name. These details are important when we don't have the full picture. Maybe you have used "ID" where you should use "userID"? Show us the implementation of `getUsers()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new to C# but I always use the below method to display the data from my database in a gridview.

```
  public void disp_data()
   {
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = "Your Query here";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      da.Fill(dt);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
      con.Close();
    }
```

Write your query instead of "Your Query here" and change the dataGridView1 to your desired dataFridView. Now call this disp_data() function in your form_load.

Comment: You might consider improving this by calling `Dispose()` on those disposable resources and not using a shared connection.